GeoServer integrated GWC not using seeded tiles
I am using the GeoServer web interface to seed my layer like you can see in this screenshot:

I hope this image shows, I have a feeling it wont. In case it doesn't: my settings are unchanged apart from

Grid Set: EPSG:900913
Format: application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile
Zoom stop: 13

When i test with my client, there is no performance gain. Moving the map around with my client fills the cache and the performance increases. Testing with curl after seeding also tells me geowebcache-cache-result: MISS.
Testing with my client (QGIS) and with curl I use this url: http://localhost:31000/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?tiled=true&width=256&height=256&REQUEST=GetTile&LAYER=ff:roads&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}
After I request a Tile twice with curl i get geowebcache-cache-result: HIT so the caching process is definitely working as intended. But somehow the seeded tiles are not being used at all.
I also severed the connection to my database once after seeding the layer (so it cant generate new tiles after) and went to the preview page under Tile Layers in GeoServer with EPSG:9009013 selected. And it was completely blank so I don't know what it is generating but it is definitely generating something (I confirmed on disk). After I requested the tiles by moving around the map on my client and then severing the connection to the database again, all the tiles that were requested were visible in the cache preview page.

The parameters tiled=true&width=256&height=256& do not belong to WMTS but I do not know if using them can make any harm or if they are just skipped.
